# Can't access build directory - symfony webpack encore

Tags: symfony, routes, webpack-encore

I have installed webpack-encore-bundle with npm on my Symfony 6.1 skeleton project and in the web browser I can't access to files in build directory (404 - route not found).

NPM successfully compiles the assets.

I'm learning to work with Docker (image php:apache-bullseye).

```
// app/webpack.config.js

const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    .splitEntryChunks()

    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    .enableLessLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

I have tried to install apache-pack (.htaccess), security-bundle, change web/encore settings and within 2 days I've not found solution.

Comment: Do you actually see files in the build directory?

Comment: @JulienB. Yes I can see it in windows and also in docker container (live via console). Tried to change owners, privileges and still 404 directly from localhost/build or included in template of controller. I think I missing something in webpack, because last time I used symfony 3.0 with assets bundle (big jump).